# How to add new variable by 3 variable value type?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with varibale job with levels - Manager, Supervisor, SelfEmployed, Official, Highly professional employee, Low skilled worker, Unskilled worker. I want to add new column with variable class where will be value 1 for high class workers value 2 for middle class workers and value 1 for low class workers.

I have a data.frame like:

```
head(df)
# Job                  
# Manager               
# Supervisor            
# Low skilled worker    
# Low skilled worker    
# Unskilled worker      
# Manager  
# Official
# Official
```

Data.frame will be like:

```
head(df)
# Job                  Class
# Manager               1
# Supervisor            1
# Low skilled worker    3
# Low skilled worker    3 
# Unskilled worker      3
# Manager               1
# Official              2
# Official              2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
df$Class[df$Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor")] <- 1
df$Class[df$Job == "Official"] <- 2
df$Class[df$Job %in% c("Low skilled worker", "Unskilled worker")] <- 3
```

Using `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Class = 
           case_when(
             Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor") ~ 1,
             Job == "Official" ~ 2,
             Job %in% c("Low skilled worker", "Unskilled worker") ~ 3
           ))
```

Using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)

df[, Class := 0][Job %in% c("Manager", "Supervisor"), Class := 1][Job == "Official", Class := 2][Job %in% c("Low skilled worker", "Unskilled worker"), Class := 3]
```

Gives us:

```
  Job                Class
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 Manager                1
2 Supervisor             1
3 Low skilled worker     3
4 Low skilled worker     3
5 Unskilled worker       3
6 Manager                1
7 Official               2
8 Official               2
```

Data:

```
structure(list(Job = c("Manager", "Supervisor", "Low skilled worker", 
"Low skilled worker", "Unskilled worker", "Manager", "Official", 
"Official")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a named vector to replace the values in the column using `base R`

```
df$Class <- setNames(c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), c("Manager", "Supervisor",
   "Official", "Low skilled worker", "Unskilled worker"))[df$Job]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Job = c("Manager", "Supervisor", "Low skilled worker", 
"Low skilled worker", "Unskilled worker", "Manager", "Official", 
"Official")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```